# Fluentbit not sending EKS logs to S3

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, fluentd, fluent-bit

I've tried to send EKS logs to S3, but logs are not being pushed to S3. But, I can able to visualize logs in Elastic search. Below is the output section of my fb-configmap.conf file.

```
    output-elasticsearch.conf: |
      [OUTPUT]
          Name            es
          Match           *
          Host            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}
          Port            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
          HTTP_User       ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER}
          HTTP_Passwd     ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWD}
          Logstash_Format Off
          Index           dev
          Replace_Dots    On
          Retry_Limit     False
    output-s3.conf: |
      [OUTPUT]
          Name                  s3
          Match                 *
          bucket                eks-logs
          region                ap-south-1
          total_file_size       250M
          s3_key_format         /%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S/$UUID.gz
          s3_key_format_tag_delimiters .-
```

As per my understanding, AWS access & secret key will be taken from the .aws/credentials path.
And do I need to install any plugin like fluent-bit-s3-plugin for this?

I've been trying to resolve this for days, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: is that your actual configuration? you don't need aws_secret_* params there. This is how the credentials are fetched: https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit-docs/blob/master/administration/aws-credentials.md

Comment: @JoséLecarosCisterna I've updated my output s3 config, still logs are not being pushed to s3.

Comment: Any log? You should set log_level to debug to see more details.

Comment: @JoséLecarosCisterna could you please tell me how to check logs and set the log_level options both?

Comment: you can set them in the SERVICE section:
[SERVICE]
    log_file fluent-bit.log
    log_level debug

Comment: @JoséLecarosCisterna issue resolved by checking the below things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can able to push to S3 after checking the below things,

- **output-s3.conf** should be given properly
- your S3 bucket should have **public** access
- should have **@INCLUDE output-*.conf** in your conf
- fluent-bit image should be **latest/stable/updated**